# ReactJS discarding all included css files

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a ReactJS application which works fine but except for one route, where the entire loaded css goes gray in the source code like this and is not applied to any element on the page:

[image]

My component is fairly simple and does one thing:

```
import React, { useEffect }  from 'react';
import { OAuthHandlerService } from '<removed>';
import {LoadingAnimation} from "components/common";

interface IOAuthPageProps {
    urlQuery: any;
}


const OAuthPage = (props: IOAuthPageProps) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        //OAuthHandlerService.onAuthTokenReceived(props.urlQuery);
    }, []);

    return (
        <LoadingAnimation show={true} showSpinner={true} message='Redirecting...' />
    );
}

export default OAuthPage;
```

I'm unable to see why all the loaded css is discarded, any ideas?

Comment: can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The issue was the route, it was going to non-existent route to load the css files:

[image]

this was fixed by specify the base URL:

```
<base href="/" />
```

The second issue was the mime type not specified, it works fine in other pages but I still specified `type="text/css"` and it is gone now.